# simPRO Tivoka Client intermittently failing

Tags: php

does anyone know how to stop the simPRO PHP Tivoka library from failing intermittently,

I have asked simPRO for support and they say that they cannot replicate the issue.
I believe it may be something to do with a `set_time_limit()` that is called somewhere in one of the libraries however I cannot find it.

Im running the following in PHP

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    //simPRO Settings

        $companyID = 0;
        use SimPro\Api\Client as SimProClient;
        use Eher\OAuth\Consumer as OAuthConsumer;
        use \Monolog\Logger;
    {   
        //if (PHP_SAPI != 'cli') die("This example must be run from the command line");

        include ("../../simpro_api_examples/vendor/autoload.php");

        define("SERVER", '**************');
        define("CONSUMER_KEY", '**************');
        define("CONSUMER_SECRET", '***************');

        $logger = new Logger('api-client');
        $logger->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('php://stderr'), Logger::INFO);
        $simPROClient = new SimProClient(SERVER , new OAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET), null);
        $simPROClient->setLogger($logger);
    }
    ?>
```

When I retrieve multiple Jobs using

```
    <?php 
    $jobIDs = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...,500);
    foreach($jobIDs as $current Job)
    {
        $jobDetails = $simPROClient -> JobRetrieve(0/*this is the company id as per their doccumentation at http://api.simpro.co/*,$currentJob);
    }
?>
```

at some point in execution (but never the same pint) it returns the following

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught Tivoka\Exception\ConnectionException: Connection
>   to "https://integrated-za.simprosuite.com/api/" failed in C:\Abyss Web
>   Server\htdocs\simpro_api_examples\vendor\tivoka\tivoka\lib\Tivoka\Client\Connection.php:114
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\Abyss Web
>   Server\htdocs\simpro_api_examples\src\SimPro\Api\Client.php(109):
>   Tivoka\Client\Connection->send(Object(Tivoka\Client\Request)) #1
>   C:\Abyss Web
>   Server\htdocs\ICG\CustomerReports\CustomerReport.php(1625):
>   SimPro\Api\Client->__call('JobRetrieve', Array) #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\Abyss Web
>   Server\htdocs\simpro_api_examples\vendor\tivoka\tivoka\lib\Tivoka\Client\Connection.php
>   on line 114

if I execute the command with fewer job ID's in the `$jobIDs` array the script executes without failure.

i have adjusted my php.ini to allow for unlimited script execution and input time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Simpro PHP library uses an old version of the [tivoka](https://github.com/marcelklehr/tivoka) RPC client that has the timeout hard-coded to 10 seconds, and because the SimproAPI is slow this very easily times out unfortunately with almost no information.  I'm assuming this is your problem.

See the timeout for version 3.1 ([that Simpro uses](https://github.com/simPRO-Software/simpro-api-php/blob/master/composer.json#L9)) set [here](https://github.com/marcelklehr/tivoka/blob/84c67d77733c3634e38c837a9dab1bff02935452/lib/Tivoka/Client/Connection.php#L105).

Personally I'm using [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) to do OAuth 1.0 requests to the Simpro API.  It's a much better client.

It's also a good idea to cache some of the data retrieved locally because   the Simpro API is awfully slow.

Comment: Thanks @Hippie for this response, I actually went through every single file in the tivoka repository and changed the timeout to suit my needs, and this seems to have done the trick for me,

I will be sure to check out guzzle in the future though